# How can I access the children of a panel element?

Tags: c#, .net

currently, my Form looks like this:

[image]

it's a panel with 2 labels inside. They are clearly linked to the panel, as on removal of the panel both labels are being removed.

However, I can't access the children of the panel when I try it in my code.

In my Form class, I would have guessed I would have to go with this:

```
this.panelName.label1
```

or

```
this.panelName.Children
```

or

```
this.panelName.Items
```

however, I can't find out how to get access to the labels withing. All of the items are public.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acccess controls inside a panel via

```
this.panelName.Controls
```

You can use

```
this.panelName.Controls.Find()
```

to find your labels or just access them via the index `Controls[i]`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able just access your label by name, like `this.label1`.

The fact of label laying "on panel" doesn't matter in this case, it means only what this label was added into `panelName.Controls` collection of panel's child controls, but this label is still member of your class and can be accesssed by name directly.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem some days ago, i did this:

```
var elements = new List<FrameworkElement>();

foreach (FrameworkElement element in yourContent.Children)
{
    // your code here
    //example:
    elements.Add(element);
    // more blabla code
}
```

EDITED, addes easier names.

it worked for me, hope it helps you!

Comment: I don't think it is good advice to do such effort for a task that is simply solved by adressing the label by its name.

Comment: u right, depends if he has to do the same things for all labels or not, i had to do same thing for many items so i did it, if he can add the name property to labels is easier, but i don't know it

Comment: Indeed for such problem this is a solution, I just do not want the questioner to think that this effort is always needed when you need to access a label inside your form.